# Sentry Android - Issue while bulding the release apk

Tags: java, android, proguard, sentry

I have configured proguard along with Sentry in my project. This is what I am getting

```
Process 'command '/tmp/.sentry-cli5730999568943770894.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any work around would be appreciated

Comment: Can you run with `SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug` environment variable and paste the logs?

Comment: Can you tell me where to put that code..?

Comment: It would need to be in an environment variable: https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: Or you can set it in Android Studio settings somehow if you're launching it from there.